# Как правильно расположить ссылки социальных сетей в правой части сайта?

Tags: html, css

верстаю данный макет и не совсем понимаю, как правильно добавить боковые ссылки социальных сетей.

[image: Home]

На данный момент есть такая реализация:

HTML:

```
<section class="home">
    <div class="container">
        <header class="header">
            <nav class="header__nav">
                <div class="header__menu">
                    <ul class="menu__list">
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Travel</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <div class="home__wrapper">
            <h1 class="home__title">Business Travel</h1>
            <p class="home__subtitle">For entrepreneurs and freelancers</p>
            <button class="button button_home">
                MORE INFO
            </button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="home__social">
        <ul class="social__links">
            <li><a href="#">Instagram</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</section>
```

CSS:

```
.social__links {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 0;
    transform: translateY(-40%);
    li {
        margin: 135px 0;
        list-style-type: none;
        transform: rotate(90deg);
    }
    a {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: 400;
        color: #ffffff;
        text-decoration: none;
    }
}
```

Одна из проблем состоит в том, что не удается адекватно настроить расстояние между ссылками, только за счёт очень большого margin, что мне кажется не совсем верным подходом.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для этого придумано свойство [writing-mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode), но с ним вроде как проблемы, хотя [Can I use](https://caniuse.com/?search=vertical-lr) пишет что всё норм у многих..

```css
.link { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 30px;
  height: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  writing-mode: vertical-lr;
  -webkit-writing-mode: vertical-lr;
}

.link a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
  <a href="#">Instagram</a>
  <a href="#">Twitter</a>
  <a href="#">Facebook</a>
</div>
```

---

По этому есть альтернативный вариант, с использованием `rotate`

```css
.link { 
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 100vh;
  height: 30px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 100%;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
}

.link a:not(:last-child) {
  margin-right: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="link">
  <a href="#">Instagram</a>
  <a href="#">Twitter</a>
  <a href="#">Facebook</a>
</div>
```